# Is there any way to compile ffmpeg library on Windows?

Tags: android, ffmpeg

Hi I have been working for weeks to compile ffmpeg library on Windows platform.But I found no way so far.Is it there any way to compile ffmpeg library on Windows 7.

I am using Cygwin on Windows.
Whenever I try to do ndk-build I get this message.

```
Android NDK: ERROR:jni/yuv2rgb/Android.mk:ffmpeg-prebuilt: LOCAL_SRC_FILES points to a missing file
Android NDK: Check that jni/ffmpeg-build/armeabi/libffmpeg.so exists  or that its path is correct
/cygdrive/D/AndroidNDK/android-ndk-r8c/build/core/prebuilt-library.mk:43: *** Android NDK: Aborting    .  Stop.
```

& while searching for solution of this error I found that I will have to compile the libraries first.For compiling by using ./build_android.sh. I got this error message.

```
./build_android.sh
./build_android.sh: line 72: ./configure: No such file or directory
```

Please please guide me what should I do.